# Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: "[Semantical Error] line?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I am trying to create a search field for the rejected transactions page in our web application project, I'm using symfony2 framework, I'm stuck coz there was an error saying,

'[Semantical Error] line 0, col 235 near 'b JOIN b.ediAk403ErrorCodes': Error: Class Matrix\MatrixEdiBundle\Entity\EdiTransaction has no association named edi997Details'

and also

'CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 235 near 'b JOIN b.ediAk403ErrorCodes': Error: Class Matrix\MatrixEdiBundle\Entity\EdiTransaction has no association named edi997Details" at /tmxpage/apache/htdocsEDI/Editracker/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php line 63 '

here is my code for that (in my repository) :

```
public function getDetails($gsNumber, $senderId, $receiverId, $page = 1, $limit = 5 ){

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $query = $em->createQuery(

        'SELECT partial a.{ediTransactionId, senderId, receiverId, gsNumber, isaNumber, fileName },

        partial b.{errorCodeId, noOfTrans},

        partial c.{errorCode, condition}

        FROM MatrixEdiBundle:EdiTransaction a

        JOIN a.edi997Details b

        JOIN b.ediAk403ErrorCodes c

        WHERE b.errorCodeId != 1

        AND a.flag = 1

        AND a.gsNumber LIKE :gsNumber

        AND a.senderId LIKE :senderId

        AND a.recieverId LIKE :receiverId')

        ->setParameter('gsNumber', "%gsNumber%")

        ->setParameter('senderId', "%senderId%")

        ->setParameter('receiverId'ssss, "%receiverId%")

        ->setFirstResult(($page-1)*$limit)

        ->setMaxResults($limit);



        $paginator = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = false );

        $paginator->setUseOutputWalkers(false);


    return $paginator;
}
```

and here is my entity code for the talble ediAk403ErrorCodes :

```
class EdiAk403ErrorCodes
{
  /**
  * @var string
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="condition", type="string", length=50,  nullable=false)
  */
 private $condition;

 /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="error_code", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
 private $errorCode;

 /**
 * Set condition
 *
 * @param string $condition
 * @return EdiAk403ErrorCodes
 */

 public function setCondition($condition)
 {
    $this->condition = $condition;

    return $this;
 }

 /**
 * Get condition
 *
 * @return string 
 */
 public function getCondition()
 {
    return $this->condition;
 }

 /**
 * Get errorCode
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
 public function getErrorCode()
 {
    return $this->errorCode;
 }

 /**
 * Get edi997Details
 *
 * @return \Matrix\MatrixEdiBundle\Entity\Edi997Details
 */
 public function getEdi997Details()
 {
    return $this->edi997Details;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems your Entity Class `EdiTransaction`  don't have an explicit doctrine relation with the table `EdiAk403ErrorCodes`. So try adding the field definition with the correct annotation in the EdiTransaction class as follow:

<kbd>EdiTransaction</kbd>

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Matrix\MatrixEdiBundle\Entity\Edi997Details", inversedBy="editTransactions")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="edit_details_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $edi997Details;
```

Hope this help

Comment: after adding that in the EdiTransaction Entity class this was the error I encountered ," MappingException: No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "Matrix\MatrixEdiBundle\Entity\EdiTransaction". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key."

Answer (score 0):

The single letters are used as a short name for a table. In your first line, you associate MatrixEdiBundle:EdiTransaction with the letter a. So `a.edi997Details` only makes sense if it's a column of the a table. I believe all you need is this:

```
    FROM MatrixEdiBundle:EdiTransaction a

    JOIN edi997Details b

    JOIN ediAk403ErrorCodes c
```

Comment: @IarsAnders after your answer I encountered this error '[Semantical Error] line 0, col 219 near 'edi997Details': Error: Class 'edi997Details' is not defined.'